# Google Chrome Wrong Flash Object Size

Tags: html, flash, google-chrome

how are you?

So, Since years the site ( Its a kind of CMS ) Just worked Fine, but about 3 days ago all the flash's object's in the Whole Site are with 300px X 150px. But it just happens in Google Chrome, in all other Browsers it just Work's fine!

How it would be fixed? Take a look at the code of the object:

```
<object >

                <param name='wmode' value='transparent' />

                <param name='movie' value='topo.swf'/>

                <param name='quality' value='high'/>

                <param name='FlashVars' value=''/>

                <embed src='topo.swf' width='970' height='21' wmode='transparent'>

                </embed>

            </object>
```

Sorry for the bad English and Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the width and height to the object tag? Like this

```
<object width='970' height='21'>
<param name='wmode' value='transparent' />
                <param name='movie' value='topo.swf'/>
                <param name='quality' value='high'/>
                <param name='FlashVars' value=''/>
                <embed src='topo.swf' width='970' height='21' wmode='transparent'>
                </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Incredible! After hours reading and rereading the code, your simple Solution solved it! It will be not that ease because it Is a CMS, and the Site isnt mine, i didnt created it, however, your simple addition of the width and height to the object tag solved it!

After reflect i Realize that Google Chrome have Flash built-in!

Anyway! Thanks Again!